# how to see contents of a file (cat file) but eliminate a certain string in many lines

Tags: linux, sed

I have a file like this:

```
ins.pro.server.pro.net
ins.pro-server2.pro.net
ins.pro-server3.pro.net
ins.pro-server4.pro.net
```

I would like to cat this file but eliminating the specific string ".pro.net" from all the lines,
so it can result like this:

```
ins.pro-server
ins.pro-server2
ins.pro-server3
ins.pro-server4
```

Thank you in advance for your help

P.S.: I have used some sed options before but it also deleted the first part from "ins.pro-server" leaving it like "ins.-server"

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I'm doing this from memory, but I believe the following should work:

cat $file | sed s/\.pro\.net//

Reference:  [Sed Tutorial by Bruce Barnett](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html)

MVP (below) is correct.  For some reason, my backslashes on the dots didn't come through (I guess I need to escape them?).  Also, the cat is redundant, because you can just add the file argument at the end, the way MVP suggested.

(I'd comment on his answer, but I don't have 50 rep yet)
(Backslashes in my answer were originally missing because I didn't escape them)

Answer (score 4):

Use this:

```
sed "s/\.pro\.net//g" file
```

First, you don't need cat for that, second, make sure to use `\.` instead of just `.`, because dot means match any symbol. It may appear to work, but it would also match string `xproynet`, which is probably not what you want.

Comment: Using single quotes rather than double quotes for `sed` commands (e.g., `sed 's/\.pro\.net//g' file`) is a good habit to get into.

Comment: @G-man: this is just matter of personal preference. I prefer to use double quotes for strings as this is C/C++ way. In shell both work fine

Comment: It's only a matter of personal preference until your store has a half-price sale, and you want to edit your price list with `sed "s/$2/$1/g"`. My point is that `sed` commands often have things in them that get interpreted by the shell if they are in double quotes.